# Why are there differences between nation names in Esperanto? / Kial estas diferencoj inter nomoj de nacioj en Esperanto?

Tags: word-formation

**English:** Hello. Why does one translate frenchmen, Italians, Germans and Poles to "Francoj", "Italoj", "Germanoj" and "Poloj"; but translates other nations as Iranians and Americans to "Irananoj" (Iran+ano+j) and "Usonanoj" (Uson+ano+j)?

**Esperanto:** Saluton. Kial oni nomas kelkajn naciojn kiel "Francoj", "Italoj", "Germanoj" kaj "Poloj"; sed nomas aliajn naciojn kiel "Irananoj" (Iran+ano+j) kaj "Usonanoj" (Uson+ano+j)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> La landonomoj en Esperanto apartenas al du kategorioj: landobazaj nomoj kaj gentobazaj nomoj.

Tiu estas la komenco de la klarigo pri la malsamaj manieroj konstrui nomojn de landoj, nacioj kaj popoloj.

Vi trovos la ceteron en [PMEG - Landoj, popoloj kaj lingvoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/propraj_nomoj/landoj_popoloj_lingvoj.html).

Comment: Alia bona verko estas _Konciza klarigo pri la landonomoj en Esperanto_ de Anna Löwenstein. Ĝi troveblas ankaŭ [rete](http://bonalingvo.org/docs/klarigoprilandonomoj.pdf).

Comment: Dankon estimataj Sinjoroj Trápani kaj Metsäkallas, pro viaj utilaj ligiloj!